# Can't get div flush with top of page

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting my wrapper div to become flush with the very top of the page. I've set the body margin/padding to zero, as well as the top margin for the wrapper div to zero with no success.

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image:url('../images/bg1.jpg');
    padding:0px; 
    margin:0px;
}

#ratio{
    text-align: center;
}

div#nav {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav img{
    padding: 5px 40px 20px 40px;
}

#task_table{
    width: 775px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#task_table td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#task_table td:first-child{
    width: 220px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

#task_table td:nth-child(2){
    width:70px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#task_table td:nth-child(3){
    padding-left: 25px;
}

#task_table td:nth-child(4){
    text-align:right;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 775px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#datecaption {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#hourscaption {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-left: 195px;
}

#taskcaption {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

#taskbar {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 15px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

#task_text {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 330px;
}

#hours_text {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 50px;
}

.delete, .successful, .unsuccessful {
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
}
```

html:

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="nav">

            <a href="index.php"><img src="images/tab1.jpg" class="navimg" id="tab1"/></a>

            <a href="completed.php"><img src="images/tab2.jpg" class="navimg" id="tab2"/></a>

            <a href="failed.php"><img src="images/tab3.jpg" class="navimg" id="tab3"/></a>

        </div>

        <span id="datecaption">DATE</span>

        <span id="hourscaption">HOURS</span>

        <span id="taskcaption">TASK</span>

            <form action="index.php" method="POST" style="margin:0;padding:0;" id="submit">

        <div id="taskbar">

                <select name="month" id="monthDD"><option>January</option><option selected="selected">February</option><option>March</option><option>April</option><option>May</option><option>June</option><option>July</option><option>August</option><option>September</option><option>October</option><option>November</option><option>December</option></select><select name="day" id="dayDD"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option selected="selected">14</option><option>15</option><option>16</option><option>17</option><option>18</option><option>19</option><option>20</option><option>21</option><option>22</option><option>23</option><option>24</option><option>25</option><option>26</option><option>27</option><option>28</option><option>29</option><option>30</option><option>31</option></select>                <select name="year" id="yearDD">

                    <option>2012</option>

                    <option>2013</option>

                    <option>2014</option>

                </select>



                <input type="text" name="hours" id="hours_text" />

                <input type="text" name="task" id="task_text" />

                <input type="Submit" value="Add Task" style="margin-left: 20px;" />

        </div></form>



        <table id="task_table"><tr id="row157"><td>February 14, 2012</td><td>0</td><td>Read</td><td><a href=""><img src="images/trash.png" class="delete" name="157"></a>

            <a href=""><img src="images/delete.png" class="failed" name="157"></a>

            <a href=""><img src="images/check.png" class="successful" name="157"></a></td></tr><tr id="row158"><td>February 14, 2012</td><td>1</td><td>Work on tasks project</td><td><a href=""><img src="images/trash.png" class="delete" name="158"></a>

            <a href=""><img src="images/delete.png" class="failed" name="158"></a>

            <a href=""><img src="images/check.png" class="successful" name="158"></a></td></tr></table>     



    </div>

</body>
```

Anyone know what's up? Thanks.

It seems to be working in the jsFiddle, oddly; http://jsfiddle.net/jsNS8/

Comment: Post your generated HTML, not the PHP source.

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see a sort of live example.

Comment: Is this live right now?  Can we get the link if so?

Comment: Does `#nav` have any top margin?

Comment: Posted full CSS as well as the generated HTML

Comment: Not live right now otherwise I'd provide a link, I'll get working on the jsfiddle

Comment: Are you sure it's a margin on a div you're seeing? Couldn't it be the padding on the top images?

Comment: It still retains the spacing even after removing all padding from the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `position:absolute` attribute.

```
#wrapper
{
position:absolute;
top:0px
}
```

Comment: Ended up going with: `position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;` to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a CSS reset file is the answer as you have effectively reset all the body element contains

Have you got any margin on the top of the #nav element? This can overlap the #wrapper causing a gap at the top of the page. I tend to use padding for such instances instead.

I hope this solves it for you!

Comment: Nope, no margin on the nav div. I'm about to post the complete CSS.

Answer (score 0):

use a css reset file before you put your css in and see if that helps

Comment: This should probably be a comment. Be careful about putting unnecessary answers in, as they could be voted down.

Answer (score 0):

try remove / adjust the element: '#nav img'

The padding of this element affection the parent element height.

Can you explain exactly what you intend to do or what is wrong.